# HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove doesn't remove cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpruntime.cache

I am trying to remove the cache using the HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(key) but invain. I wonder what are the best practices for using HttpRuntime.Cache.

Regards

Comment: Please provide some more details of what exactly you're trying to do and what is/isn't happening - preferably with some example code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.remove.aspx) method works perfectly fine and removes the item from the cache given its key. Here's an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // add an item to the cache
        HttpRuntime.Cache["foo"] = "bar";
        Console.WriteLine(HttpRuntime.Cache["foo"]); // prints bar

        // remove the item from the cache
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("foo");
        Console.WriteLine(HttpRuntime.Cache["foo"]); // prints empty string
    }
}
```

It's probably the way you are using it that is wrong. Unfortunately this hasn't been specified in your question so that's as far as we can help.

Answer (score 2):

I once spent a fun-filled hour tracking down something that looked very similar: I removed something from cache only to find it back in there again. Turned out to be a remove-trigger that put it back each time. Look for side effects like that.

Comment: This^.

Remember, after HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove() has been called, the delegate 'CacheItemRemoved' callback method will fire, and I would guess you're re-adding the item inside there.